# Adding a row based on cell value from other sheet

Tags: excel

How can I add rows starting from ROW 5 in "Grouped Data" worksheet based on a cell value from another sheet(in this case, D4 from "Frequency Distribution" worksheet)?

[Grouped Data worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erhLj.png)

[Frequency Distribution worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMaB3.png)

Comment: You already used `'Frequency Distribution`!D6` in row 5. So, use `'Frequency Distribution`!D4` to get data from `D4` cell fromfrequency distribution.

Comment: the formula in A5 has nothing to do with my problem. What I want is to add a row starting from row 5 based on the  value in 'Frequency Distribution'!D4.

Comment: Try doing a search online of existing documentation where possible, see if you can post an answer to your own question (if that's possible) after checking out this content: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/08/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/